# regex for parsing resource (.rc) files

Tags: c++, regex, mfc, internationalization

Ulimately I just wanted to extract strings from the .rc file so I could translate them, but anything that goes with .rc files works for me.

Comment: I don't have any .rc files, can you give me a sample one so that I can create a regex for it?

Comment: Perhaps [RC-WinTrans
Software Localizer](http://www.schaudin.com/web/products_v8.aspx) ? Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with them, but in the the company I work for people use an old version of it for translation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider usage of [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) and [.PO files](http://gnu.cs.pu.edu.tw/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html), if your program fits GNU license

1) I'd suggest extracting from .rc files using state machine algorithm.

```
void ProcessLine(const char * str)
{
   if (strstr(str, " DIALOG"))
      state = Scan;
   else if (strstr(str, " MENU"))
      state = Scan;
   else if (strstr(str, " STRINGTABLE"))
      state = Scan;
   else if (strstr(str, "END"))
      state = DontScan;

   if (state == Scan)
   {
      const char * cur = sLine;
      string hdr = ...// for example "# file.rc:453"
      string msgid;
      string msgid = "";
      while (ExtractString(sLine, cur, msgid))
      {
         if (msgid.empty())
            continue;
         if (IsPredefined(msgid))
            continue;
         if (msgid.find("IDB_") == 0 || msgid.find("IDC_") == 0)
            continue;
         WritePoString(hdr, msgid, msgstr);
      }
   }
}
```

2) When extracting string inside ExtractString() you should consider that char " is represented as "", and there are also chars like \t \n \r. So state machine is also a good option here.

The following string:

```
LTEXT           "Mother has washed ""Sony"", then \taquarium\\shelves\r\nand probably floors",IDC_TEXT1,24,14,224,19
```

represents such label on a dialog:

```
Mother has washed "Sony", then aquarium\shelves
and probably floors
```

3) Then on program startup you should load .po file via gettext and for each dialog translate its string on startup using a function like this:

```
int TranslateDialog(CWnd& wnd)
{
    int i = 0;
    CWnd *pChild;
    CString text;

    //Translate Title
wnd.GetWindowText(text);
LPCTSTR translation = Translate(text);
    window.SetWindowText(translation);

    //Translate child windows
    pChild=wnd.GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
    while(pChild)
    {
        i++;
    Child->GetWindowText(Text);//including NULL
        translation = Translate(Text);
        pChild->SetWindowText(translation);
        pChild = pChild->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps? (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/regexp/thread/5e87fce9-ec73-42eb-b2eb-c821e95e0d31/)

They are using the following regex to find the stringtable in the rc source:

(?<=\bSTRINGTABLE\s+BEGIN\s+).*?(?=\s+END\b)

Edit - And you can read the key values pairs with the following statement with the MultiLine option:

@"\s+(.*?)\s+""(.*)""";

Answer (score 1):

Although rc files seems an obvious starting point for translation, it's not. 
The job of developers is to make sure the app is translatable. It's not to manage translations. Starting translations from the exe, although somewhat counter-intuitive, is a way better idea.
Read more about it here: http://www.apptranslator.com/misconceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a [SED](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1229) script.

By running this command line: **sed.exe -n -f sed.txt test.rc**

The following [SED](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1229) script will extract all the *quoted strings* from the input **test.rc** file:

```
# Run Script Using This Command Line
#
#   sed.exe -n -f sed.txt test.rc
#

# Check for lines that contain strings
/\".*\"/ {
    # print the string part of the line only
    s/\(.*\)\(\".*\"\)\(.*\)/\2/ p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case rc, better use advanced parser like http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/java/windows-resource-file-parser-and-converter

Answer (score -2):

[ResxCrunch](http://resxcrunch.com) will be out sometimes soon. 
It will edit multiple resource files in multiple languages in one single table.